# Unrecognized options swift_mailer under sonata_notification.consumers error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

I am trying to use sonataNotificationBundle, I did all configurations as mentioned in documentation, but I am getting following error,

```
Unrecognized options swift_mailer under sonata_notification.consumers
```

Before that I was getting

```
Unrecognized options consumer under sonata_notification
```

I dig in to sonata/NotificationBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php, there

```
->arrayNode('consumers')
```

is written in code but in documentation it is "consumer"

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/notification/2-1/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html

I changed to it "consumers" after that I am now getting below error

```
Unrecognized options swift_mailer under sonata_notification.consumers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typo in the doc (swift_mailer is a 2.0 configuration, the doc is not up to date at all), you can fork and edit it.

Just delete the consumers option in the configuration file.

Comment: after adding below lines of code, I could make it work   ->arrayNode('consumers')
                ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('swift_mailer')
                        ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                        ->children()
                            ->scalarNode('path')->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                 ->end()
            ->end()

Comment: don't do that, you need to delete the consumers option in your config.yml, it will add the default value automatically.

Comment: worked ! thanks but emails are getting stored to database but not getting sent to email address. How to trigger swiftmailer consumer? I have created another question for this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615547/sonatanotificationbundle-emails-getting-stored-to-database-but-swiftmailer-cons

Comment: also please modify your answer to mention to remove consumers from configuration so that I can accept it. But still ideally if the option is given it should work properly.